# After downloading NDK r8 whether I need to download more or not?

Tags: android, android-ndk, installation

I have downloaded android-ndk-r8b.zip(180MB),but I want to know if I need to download anything else?
I am using the NDK because I want to use C/C++ native code (used in tesseract3.0 project) in my android library.
I am using Eclipse IDE(Indigo).
I also installed the following

1. installed CDT from Eclipse update site http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo.
2. installed Android SDK + NDK Plugins from Eclipse update site https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to code under Indigo you do not need anything else, however i found Eclipse to be an horrible IDE for C and C++ and i suggest to code with just a text editor and a terminal because it's just more flexible and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

To develop in android using eclipse you need: Android-SDK, Android-NDK and eclipse plugin.

If you use windows you also need to install cygwin version 1.7 or greater.
You need gnu Make 3.81 or later and a recent gawk (include them during cygwin installation).

Comment: With the latest NDK, you don't need cygwin anymore!

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html for the detailed explanations. In addition to eclipse and SDK, you should install [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). Form version 20, [the plugin supports native development](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin), in addition to java.